Recommended tags disappear before I can choose one
Whenever I try to look for the right tag I can't just click on the recommended ones because they appear on the screen for a millisecond and then disappear.
The worst problem is that they get recommended multiple times even if I try to write the tag manually so I have to bring the cursor back again, after nearly ever letter.
It sometimes also happens when writing questions. But it's easier to write questions because you can change it up and the recommendations stop.
I have faced this problem in Math.SE and in this one too I don't think it's a one site related problem.
EDIT:I've not faced this problem in edge, only on chrome. OS is Windows 11 Home
EDIT:This also happens with inbox and the achievements option. It doesn't stay long enough

Which browser and OS are you using? please [edit]  your question to include those details, including exact versions. If you try on a different browser /OS, does the same problem occur?

Also, if you can record your screen when this happens and save as gif animation, would be great.

Still not enough, what version of Chrome? If old version, this explains the bug. (and rene did clearly ask for the version.)

You can see the version by browsing to: chrome://version/. (you have to copy the link and browse directly, chrome or SE don't render this as link)

@ShadowWizard Version 131.0.6778.205 (Official Build) (64-bit)

So it's not the browser version, but still something on your side. Disable all your browser extensions or plugins, you likely installed something that mess with the client side code on sites and cause such problems. See this for a quick way to do that. Assuming this will "fix" the problem, you can then enable them again, and disable them one by one until you find which is causing the problem, and report it or ask its developer to fix it.
